What's the meaning of the individual characters in the ACE "user:fakeusername:allow:rwxpdDaARWcCo:----"?
I have output like the following and would like to understand the meaning of the individual ACE characters after the basic permissions "rwx". Sadly, I couldn't find any docs about those. It might be of interest that the underlying file system used is BTRFS.
$ ls -lae
total 22348
drwxrwxrwx+ 1 fakeusername users 54 Jun 21 13:52 .
[0] user:fakeusername:allow:rwxpdDaARWcCo:fd-- (level: 1)
[1] everyone::allow:--x----------:fd-- (level: 2)
[2] owner::allow:rwxpdDaARWcCo:fdi- (level: 2)
[3] user:fakeusername:allow:rwxpdDaARWcCo:---- (level: 2)

drwxrwxrwx+ 1 fakeusername users 70 Jun 21 12:32 ..
-rwxrwxrwx+ 1 fakeusername users 2184672 Jun 21 12:32 file1.psd
[0] user:fakeusername:allow:rwxpdDaARWcCo:---- (level: 2)
[1] everyone::allow:--x----------:---- (level: 3)
[2] user:fakeusername:allow:rwxpdDaARWcCo:---- (level: 3)

So what's the meaning of pdDaARWcCo?
Because of BTRFS, upper-case C might correspond to NODATACOW? C is documented for that purpose for chattr:

no copy on write (C)

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chattr.1.html

Is this actually on Linux? No, ACE flags would have nothing whatsoever to do with chattr flags (as those are global file-level), but regular Linux only supports POSIX draft ACLs that only have the rwx flags (and GNU Coreutils ls doesn't have the -e flag either), so this doesn't look anything like Linux output to me. [It is however very likely to be in the NFSv4 ACL format, which has many similarities to SMB/Windows ACLs.]

Is this actually on Linux? Yes: Linux ds218 4.4.302+ #69057 SMP Fri Jan 12 17:02:59 CST 2024 x86_64 GNU/Linux synology_apollolake_218+ Though it might be that the NAS applied some NFS stuff even without using that package at all. I can't even do so manually because the package isn't enabled.

Are you running the ls command on the NAS via SSH, or are you running it locally on your laptop? If the former, it might be that Synology has a custom ls and a custom ACL system (as Linux certainly doesn't have the one you show). I don't know which package you're referring to, but, much like "SMB ACLs" are equal to NTFS ACLs on Windows (it wouldn't make practical sense for them to be two different mechanisms), NFSv4 ACLs are indeed sometimes used by filesystems on disk, and I wouldn't rule out Synology having a custom implementation of them.

Are you running the ls command on the NAS via SSH[...]? Yes. I don't get your point: Did they apply the RichACLs-stuff not in upstream yet to their kernel or are NFSv4-ACLs simply stored that way whenever those kernel modules are available or ...? Those ACLs need to be stored somewhere in the end and NFSv4 is installed, it's just not running or actively used by me.
